# Is there a word or phrase for someone who always tries to get more than he needs or deserves?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

This person always tries to get more than he/she needs, especially gratuities, gifts and souvenirs. Looking or sounding ridiculous is no barrier for him/her.

Comment: Anything wrong with *greedy*?

Comment: Also avaricious, acquisitive, covetous, grasping, materialistic, gluttonous, self-indulgent, insatiable, wolfish.

Comment: I would have said either "greedy" or "mooch."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider *moocher*.  *Merriam Webster* defines *[mooch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moocher)* as

> to ask for and get things from other people without paying for them or doing anything for them: *he's always mooching off of his friends, even though he can easily pay his own way*

This usage may be limited to the US.

Similarly, *[scrounger](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scrounger)*

> A person who borrows from or lives off others. *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

This also appears to be an Americanism.

A related term is *[schnorrer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/schnorrer)*, often used in American English, though derived from Yiddish and ultimately German

> (informal , chiefly North American) 
>   A beggar or scrounger; a layabout. *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: I don't know where *scrounger* comes from originally, but it's well known in the UK, especially in political arguments relating to [out-of-work people claiming benefits](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/the-scroungers-fight-back-the-welfare-claimants-battling-to-alter-stereotypes-9619783.html) (welfare). I've never heard of *schnorrer*. In the UK *moocher* or, more usually as a verb *mooching*, means hanging around in an indecisive sort of way. eg teenagers with nothing better to do, mooching around in the park.

Answer (score 2):

ODO: [grasping](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grasping)

Avaricious; greedy:

- *they were regarded as grasping landlords*
- *A grasping and greedy ethos seems to be what grips most of our citizens.*
- *It's a grasping, greedy society, fuelled by educational expectation and privilege.*
- *She hid it under the carpets to keep it from the grasping claws of her greedy brother, who was a man not averse to physical violence and who put pressure on everybody to help him service his frequent debts.*

ODO: [entitled](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/entitled)

Believing oneself to be inherently deserving of privileges or special treatment:

- *kids who feel so entitled and think the world will revolve around them*
- *his pompous, entitled attitude*
- *A few very loud and very entitled parents have now made the school board their personal forum.*
- *My sweet, sweet daughter has become a very entitled, insecure young woman.*
- *It was because of those wealthy people and their entitled behaviors that we removed our oldest son from public education.*